# log in with google account,using email and then creating password for app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I am new in iOS development and I want to use Google login in my app where email is taken from Google account but the password is created for the app and creates new account for the app and stores it on server. How to do this ?

Comment: Follow step by step guideline on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

Comment: @Sujit i have done this,i've fetched user's info but i want to create account for my app for that i have to create password using google email.

Comment: your question is not clear. If you are getting user info then you should get the user email id from it. What you expecting for password?

Comment: @Sujit sorry question is not clear :(      email-google id  ..... create password- password....... confirm password-password .... contact number-9999999999 .. so here id will be from google and password will be created when it return to app. i hope it's bit clear now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is steps to Get Email from Google Sign in :

Step 1 : Use Pod `pod 'Google/SignIn`

Step 2: Import `#import <Google/SignIn.h>` (This import in either Bridging-Header for `Swift` or in your controller for `Objective c`)

Add `GIDSignInUIDelegate`

Step 3: on Load of Login View or Screen where you want e-mail

**=== For Swift ===**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

**=== For Objective C ===**

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Step 4: Implement delegate methods of `GIDSignIn`

**=== For Swift ===**

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let name = user.profile.name
        let email = user.profile.email
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**=== For Objective C ===**

```
 - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
    didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
         withError:(NSError *)error{

        if(error == nil){
            NSLog(@"%@",user.profile.name);
            NSLog(@"%@",user.profile.email);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
}
```

Step 5: Use Get email Address in your Login View as pre-filled and add other fields as per you requirement e.g Password , Confirm Password, Contact Number, etc..

Note : you can also use currentUser object from GIDSignIn shared Instance.

**=== For Swift ===**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.profile.email
```

**=== For Objective C ===**

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] currentUser].profile.email
```

Hope this helps you.

do let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @ShikhaSharma This is not much code you can convert in to objective c... Otherwise I ll convert it after couple of hours. I am busy with some other task..

Comment: okay,yes am trying to convert, but please post objective c code as well, in case i fail to convert,i can use your answer :) thank you for help

Comment: it is showing a white screen after showing login view. and then retrieving data from google account. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123323/discussion-between-shikha-sharma-and-ketan-p).

Comment: @KetanP, I have login and get the user details but i need user gender details from Objective-C how to get the gender and identifier, please suggest me any one.